# sqlite3, adjacent rows (before and after)

Tags: sql, select, sqlite

I have a table:

```
table (
 pk int auto_increment, 
 ctx int not null, 
 msg text not null
)
```

I wanna select, given some PK, 10 rows before and 10 rows after. The thing is, I cannot rely on PK like (select * from table where pk < v_pk and pk > v_pk-10) because they're not adjacent, there might be a row which has nothing to do with the result, given the 'ctx'.

Thanks!

Comment: Note that there is no such thing as _adjacent_ in relational databases. You don't know/shouldn't assume how the data is stored, or how it will be retrieved. What you need to do is to use an `ORDER BY` clause to impose an order, then pick just the data you need.

Comment: What? Sorry, didn't get it. Of course there's order, given certain numeric PK.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
(select t.*
 from table t.*
 where pk <= YOURVALUE
 order by pk desc
 limit 11
) union all
(select t.*
 from table t.*
 where pk > YOURVALUE
 order by pk asc
 limit 10
)
```

The `order by` shouldn't really do a sort because you are ordering by the primary key.

Answer (score 0):

There is no *simple* way I know of to "get n rows either side of a value". Relational databases are set based, not position based.

You can try something like this:

```
    SELECT *
    FROM SO25110036 as a
    WHERE 
    a.pk = 11
    OR
    (
     a.pk < 11
     and 3 >= 
      (select count(*)
       from SO25110036 as b
       where b.pk >= a.pk
       and b.pk < 11
       )
     )
    OR
    (
     a.pk > 11
     and 3 >= 
      (select count(*)
       from SO25110036 as c
       where c.pk <= a.pk
       and c.pk > 11
       )
     )
    order by pk
    ;
```

Which I implemented as a fiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/b4595/4
For test purposes it gets 3 rows either side of the row with the 11 value, as well as that row. Also, try without the `ORDER BY`.

There may be a better solution using sqlite specific syntax, but I'm not an sqlite user.

Comment: Yeah, I considered that, but I'm afraid it's too slow cause of the select count(*)... Thank you